# Add a full photo path to a img src using jquery

Tags: jquery, image

```
 <img id="lotImgtemp" src="" height="148px" width="200px" border="0">
    var photonames=$("#loyaltymemPhoto").val();     //1.jpg         
    $("#lotImgtemp").attr("src","localhost/sumerdia/uploaded_photos/'+ photonames +'");
```

How to add the value to  img src ?

output i get the same  `"localhost/sumerdia/uploaded_photos/'+ photonames +'"`

output i need is `"localhost/sumerdia/uploaded_photos/1.jpg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#lotImgtemp").attr("src","localhost/sumerdia/uploaded_photos/'+ photonames +'");
```

try

```
$("#lotImgtemp").attr("src","localhost/sumerdia/uploaded_photos/"+ photonames);
```